# How to unpickle a model in python 3X which is pickled in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have pickled a model in python 2.7 with following sentence

```
import pickle
with open('filename','w') as f:
    pickle.dump(model, f)
```

How I am in python 3.X and what to unpickle the model, but get error

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 4: invalid start byte
```

The code I tried is:

```
import pickle
with open('filename','rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You pickle with `'w'` but you unpickle with `rb`... So maybe that's the problem...
- The other thing I found out: `0x86` can be decoded using `latin-1`. So maybe you can try to change this, *or both.*

I also read in the [pickle docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) that the pickle protocoll is automatically detected and should not cause the problem. So it seems to be all about encoding...